# What is the finest locally convex topology that coincides with the weak one on equicontinuous sets

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

In this book [Perturbative Algebraic Quantum Field Theory](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-25901-7) at page 26 the author says

> We equip $E'$    with the finest locally convex topology $\gamma$ that coincides
> with the weak one on equicontinuous sets

Where $E$ is a locally convex topological vector spaces and $E'$ its dual.

What is this topology $\gamma$?

Comment: It's a definition, tell us what you don't understand about that definition? It's perfectly clear if you know what equicontinuous sets are. Do you know the definition of those? If so, add to the question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, it is a theorem of Grothendieck that this locally convex topology is precisely the topology of unifom convergence on the  pre-compact subsets of $E$ which is thus generated by the seminorms $$p_K(\varphi)=\sup\{|\varphi(x)|: x\in K\}$$ with all such sets $K$. This should be in utmost generality in Koethe's book §21.7.

For complete locally convex spaces $E$, a version of the theorem is in the book *Introduction to Functional Analysis* of Meise and Vogt, lemma 24.21.

**Edit.** The finest locally convex topology which agrees with the weak$^*$-topology on all equicontinuous sets is the topology of uniform convergence on pre-compact sets **only for metrizable locally convex spaces**. This is (a version of) the Banach-Dieudonné theorem.

Comment: What is the name of  Koethe's book

Comment: Topological Vector Spaces I.